# CSS Image Transition in list

Tags: css

I realise this coding should be relatively simple, however, I've been researching, trying and failing so would love some help. I have a feeling I'm struggling because I've placed my images in a list. Here's my coding.

Index file:

```
<div id="gallery" style="margin-top:-30px;">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <img src="images/IMG_2069mandapsmall.jpg"/>
            <span><img src="images/IMG_2069mandaplarge.jpg"/></span></li>
        <li>
            <img src="images/IMG_0014flowerssmall.jpg"/>
            <span><img src="images/IMG_0014flowerslarge.jpg"/></span></li>
        <li>
            <img src="images/IMG_2672garlandsmall.jpg"/>
            <span><img src="images/IMG_2672garlandlarge.jpg"/></span></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

CSS file:

```
ul, li {
margin:0; padding:0;
}

ul {
position: relative;
width: 1200px;
height: auto;
margin: auto;
}

li {
list-style-type:none;
}

ul li span img {
display: none;
}

ul li:hover span {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
}

ul li:hover span img{
display: inline;
}
```

Basically I would love to see the large image to slowly appear when you hover over the small image. Perhaps some sort of fade transition? Some help would be much appreciated.

Shikz

UPDATE:
Ok, so I've fiddled with the coding and managed to get a fade effect using the following code:

```
ul li span img {
/*display: none;*/
opacity: 0;
transition: opacity 2s;
-webkit-transition: opacity 2s;
}

ul li:hover span {
/*position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;*/
}

ul li:hover span img{
/*display: inline;*/
opacity: 1;
}
```

Only problem now is that the images are not being displayed on the page where I want them to be displayed. When I attempt to put in position:absolute the opacity transition effect no longer works correctly. Why is this the case?

Comment: in css you could use transition with opacity from 0 to 1 when hovered

Comment: I tried that but unfortunately couldn't get it to work. Must be doing something wrong. Is it possible to see some coding incorporated into the coding I've written in the question? Would really appreciate that.

Comment: I don't believe you can get that effect with only CSS, would a jQuery solution be satisfactory?

Comment: I know absolutely nothing about JQuery but am happy to give it a go. I just liked the simplicity of CSS. jQuery seems quite complex.

Comment: I've fixed the problem about the position:absolute. Pretty much just did individual positioning for each image in my Index file. Probably not considered clean or crisp but it works.

Comment: @Shikz , hello, here is some code to show the idea http://codepen.io/anon/pen/CeIuG